# tap gesture recognizer won't target-action

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uitapgesturerecognizer

I added a tap gesture recognizer into a UICollectionView but when I try to target action with control drag into the implementation of the controller the tap gesture recognizer will not add a method. Any ideas as to what may be happening?

Comment: Actually, my mistake. Deleted my answer. I just checked and you can apparently just control-drag right in to the @implementation. Not sure why this is not working for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the following must be true:

- You must ensure that you've specified the subclass in Interface Builder (e.g. if putting this method in your view controller, make sure you have the view controller's subclass specified for your scene in Interface Builder);

  [image]
- If linking the action to an existing, the method must be in the implementation of the class for your must have a "return type" of `IBAction` (it behaves like a `void`, but you must specify `IBAction` or else IB won't let you link up the action), e.g.:

  ```
  - (IBAction)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
  {
      // do whatever I want to handle the tap here
  }
  ```

  If a method has `void` or some other return type specified, Interface Builder will not let you to establish the connection.

Personally, I develop the UI elements in Interface Builder first, and then control drag to the `@interface` and let Interface Builder actually add both the interface and shell of an implementation for me, and then add my code to that.

Comment: So turns out my controller had the wrong class so I fixed that and now I can drag and create an IBAction but I still cannot connect to my pre-existing Target-Action method which returns IBAction?

Comment: @user2076774 Whenever I stumbled across these issues, it was always failure to specify subclasses properly or improper method signature (e.g. `IBAction` return type and one parameter). Without seeing the method definition or your project, it's hard to say what's going on in your project. If you upload it somewhere, I'm happy to take a look.

Comment: Hey so it seems to be a bug with Xcode because I restared Xcode and it worked! You managed to help me with it though so thank you!